# ASP.Net Core 3 + React Web App - Seeing the resource busy error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

Created a ASP.Net Core 3 web app with React using Visual Studio 2019. When I try to run the application in visual studio, I am seeing the following error.

I tried running Visual Studio as administrator, but did not help.

Failed to compile.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Information:
./src/index.js

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'

Answer (score 1):

I navigated to the folder "ClientApp" using command prompt.
Deleted node_modules folder.

1. Ran npm install

Then when I run the project from Visual Studio, no error seen.